# R output format with word in inside

Tags: r

```
I=2 
J=2 
A=c(1,1)
```

I want to create a function with the above arguments which will produce an output in this format:

```
cell (1,1) --> support set = (0,0)
cell (1,2) --> support set = (0,1)
cell (2,1) --> support set = (1,0)
cell (2,2) --> support set = (1,1)
```

Here if the first element of **cell** matches with the first element of **A**, output 0, else 1. Same for the second element.
My question is how to create this kind of output format with words in r? I have no clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```r
cell_support <- function(I, J, A)
{
  cat("cell(", I, ", ", J, ") --> support set = (", 
      1 - (I == A[1]), ", ", 1 - (J == A[2]), ")\n", sep = "")
}

cell_support(I = 1, J = 2, A = c(2, 2))
#> cell(1, 2) --> support set = (1, 0)

cell_support(I = 2, J = 1, A = c(1, 1))
#> cell(2, 1) --> support set = (1, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This exactly what I am looking for. Though I modified a little bit.  I modified this ```1 - (I == A[1])``` to ```+! (I == A[1])```